# CSS not apply for dynamically created html

Tags: jquery

CSS does not apply to the dynamically added select list. But when I hard coded the select list, it applies correctly. So where I did wrong in my code. Please let me know.

```
$('#multiple-label-example').append(
    '<option>'+skillsObj[cnt].skillName+'</option>'
);
```

CSS does not apply to the above line. But it's working fine for hard coded select list.

```
var url= "/ajax/gDirectory/getAllskills.htm";
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
             url: url,
            contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            success : function(result1) {
                var skillsObj = JSON.parse(result1);
                $('#tabpage_4').append("<div class='side-by-side clearfix'></div><table><tr><td><h3>Skills & Expertise  :</h3></td><td id='skillstd'><select data-placeholder='Type skills here'  multiple class='chosen-select' style='width:300px;' tabindex='18' id='multiple-label-example'></select></td></tr></table>");
                for (cnt = 0; cnt < skillsObj.length; cnt++) 
                    $('#multiple-label-example').append('<option>'+skillsObj[cnt].skillName+'</option>');
            }
          }); 

          (function($){
              var config = {
                      '.chosen-select'           : {},
                      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
                      '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
                      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
                      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
                    }

                 for (var selector in config) {
                       $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
                      }  

              })(jQuery132);
          document.getElementById("smallimagesDiv4").style.display="none";
```

Comment: $(selector).chosen(config[selector]); not apply for above select list.but if i put <select data-placeholder='Type skills here'  multiple class='chosen-select' style='width:300px;' tabindex='18' id='multiple-label-example'><option>Testing</option></select></td></tr></table>" then its working fine

Comment: Then it might an issue in the CSS, are you using the CORRECT CSS selector? i.e. `.className`?

Comment: yes is there any diff between <option>Testing</option>  and $('#multiple-label-example').append(
    '<option>'+skillsObj[cnt].skillName+'</option>'
);..after dyanmically added then its not showing properly

Comment: Could you please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: No, there is no difference..I think the issue is with the CSS!

Comment: I am using plugin...for that so it will take more time....problem is hard coded working fine.but dynamically not working

Comment: but you don't use css you use javascript!

Comment: yes i m used javascript

Comment: Thanks to every1 i solved that....:)

Comment: so, how you solve it? :-)

Comment: $(selector).chosen(config[selector]); function put in ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Success function, you have to fire chosen update method again, so dynamically added options can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

shyamji is right. You have to trigger the chosen:updated as below:

```
                 target.trigger("chosen:updated");
```